# Count number of occurrences of an array without overlap in another array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a `mxn` matrix `A`, where `m%t = n%t = 0`, so that a smaller `txt` matrix `B` tiles the matrix without borders or overlaps. I want to check if `A` consists entirely of tiles from `B` without calculating a tiling as an intermediate step as efficiently as possible. Furthermore for my special use case, it is not necessary to know `B`. It is enough to test if `A` strictly repeats itself every `txt` tile in every direction.

Numeric examples:

```
A = [[1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 1]]
B.shape = [2,2]
--> True
B.shape = [1,1]
--> False
```

So far, I calculate a comparison matrix `C`, which simply is a tiling of `B` to fit the size of `A`:

```
import numpy as np
x,y      = B.shape
x_a, y_a = A.shape
x_t = x_a/x
y_t = y_a/y
B_dash = A[:x, :y]
C = np.tile(B_dash,(x_t, y_t))
np.count_nonzero(A-C)
```

Is there a faster way, without calculating `C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Appproach #1 :** It seems we are counting the number of occurrences of B in A as distinct blocks. So, we can use [`skimage.util.view_as_blocks`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks as viewW

out = np.count_nonzero((viewW(A, B.shape) == B).all((2,3)))
```

**Appproach #2 :** Staying with `NumPy`, we would have -

```
m1,n1 = A.shape
m2,n2 = B.shape
out = np.count_nonzero((A.reshape(m1//m2,m2,n1//n2,n2) == B[:,None]).all((1,3)))
```

Sample runs -

```
In [274]: A
Out[274]: 
array([[2, 0, 2, 0],
       [5, 3, 5, 1],
       [3, 3, 2, 6],
       [1, 0, 3, 1]])

In [275]: B
Out[275]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [1, 0]])

In [276]: np.count_nonzero((viewW(A, B.shape) == B).all((2,3)))
Out[276]: 1



In [278]: A
Out[278]: 
array([[2, 0, 3, 3],
       [5, 3, 1, 0],
       [3, 3, 2, 6],
       [1, 0, 3, 1]])

In [279]: B
Out[279]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [1, 0]])

In [280]: np.count_nonzero((viewW(A, B.shape) == B).all((2,3)))
Out[280]: 2
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that `viewW` doesn't produce a memory object with shape A, but rather one, with shape B ? In my tests, it's a little faster for big arrays. Didn't benchmark the memory usage yet.

Comment: @Dschoni Well, it creates a windowed view into the array `A` with the shape of `B` as the window parameter, so no additional memory usage there.

Comment: Caveat for Approach #1: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/util/shape.py:92: RuntimeWarning: Cannot provide views on a non-contiguous input array without copying.

Comment: @Dschoni Yes, it expects a contiguous array there.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the result without generating C. You can do it by:

```
x,y      = B.shape
x_a, y_a = A.shape
np.array_equal(A[:, :y_a-y], A[:, y:]) and np.array_equal(A[:x_a-x, :], A[x:, :])
```

That is, to compare A's first `y_a-y` columns and its last `y_a-y` columns, then do similar things for rows. I haven't test the code above, but it should be faster, because with this method `numpy` will not allocate new memories.

The last statement can be optimized to:

```
np.array_equal(A[:, :y_a-y], A[:, y:]) and np.array_equal(A[:x_a-x, :y_a], A[x:, :y_a])
```

Because if the first term is `True`, we've already known that A's columns are repeated t times.